# Flutter Supabase - custom JWT

Tags: flutter, jwt, supabase

I was using Firebase SMS auth, generate a JWT, and use the Firebase auth token as the user token in SupaBase:

Supabase.instance.client.auth.setAuth(theCustomJWTtoken);

In the 1.x version of the supabase_flutter package setAuth has been removed, and the documentation is not helping me figure out how I can continue to use custom JWTs in Flutter.

Any ideas (preferably with code)?

Answer (score 2):

```
final supabase = SupabaseClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey, headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer $access_token',
});
```

This worked. Was posted on GitHub [here](https://github.com/supabase/supabase-flutter/issues/255#issuecomment-1308353609):